# Apache-Airflow fernet_key problems with airflow test

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I got a problem when I try to use airflow test a FileSensor:
[Filesensor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AniOg.png)

I use docker-compose for starting the Container:

start of docker-compose
version: "3"
services:
        jupyter:
                container_name: "jupyter-service"
                image: jupyter/scipy-notebook
                ports:
                        - 8888:8888
        superset:
                container_name: "superset-service"
                image: tylerfowler/superset
                ports:
                        - 8088:8088
        postgres:
                container_name: "postgres_db"
                image: postgres
                environment:
                        - POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
                        - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
                        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
                        - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
                volumes:
                        - ./pg_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/
                ports:
                        - 5432:5432

```
    minio:
            container_name: "minio-service"
            image: minio/minio
            environment:
                    - MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=minio
                    - MINIO_SECRET_KEY=minioKey123
            volumes:
                    - ./minio_volume:/data/
            ports:
                    - 9000:9000
            command: server /data

    apistar:
            container_name: "api-service"
            build: services/apistar
            volumes:
                    - ./services/apistar/api:/usr/src/app
            ports:
                    - 8000:8000
            command: gunicorn app:app -b 0.0.0.0:8000

    webserver:
            container_name: "airflow"
            restart: always
            image: puckel/docker-airflow
            volumes:
                    - ./services/airflow/airflow.cfg:/usr/local/airflow/airflow.cfg
                    - ./services/airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
                    - ./services/airflow/shared_files:/usr/local/airflow/shared_files
            environment:
                    - LOAD_EX=n
                    - EXECUTOR=Local
                    - FERNET_KEY=l-OhyQHu1gNyu7rFmr1amZZfsp2qhpnfp8GwuR-zyw8=
            depends_on:
                    - postgres
            environment:
                    - EXECUTOR=Local
            ports:
                    - 8080:8080
            command: webserver

    scheduler:
            container_name: "airflow_scheduler"
            restart: always
            image: puckel/docker-airflow
            depends_on: 
                    - webserver
            environment:
                    - LOAD_EX=n
                    - FERNET_KEY=l-OhyQHu1gNyu7rFmr1amZZfsp2qhpnfp8GwuR-zyw8=
            command: scheduler
```

volumes:
        pg_volume:
                driver: local

end of docker-compose

When I activate the DAG it works to my satisfaction. But when I want to test is via airflow test I got the following result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyhXe.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbbfL.png)

I found not much about this, but what I found was that I have to specify the FernetKey with the entrypoint, maybe it was wrong.
Hope you can help me..

Thank you in advance! Hope you are all fine.
kind regards

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I have the same question and am having trouble finding the solution

Comment: I have the same problem too :(

Comment: I found a solution two days later. I guess the music was not in the Fernet-Key from the airflow-service as the error message suggest. In my case it helped me to delete the Fernet-Key Microservices Environment Variables, cleaned up my code, tested it standalone, after this everything worked fine. If you have any question do not hesitate to ask, may I could help you more than just telling what helped in my case.